# Suggestion regarding core-data based apps

Tags: objective-c

what are the steps to simply create a core-data application(using window based apps).  without using core data for storage at the time of creating new project

Answer (score 1):

- add and configure your managed object model
- define the managed object model, persistent store coordinator and managed object context objects somewhere in your app (often the app delegate object)
- convert your controllers to use the new model

In the conversion step, I normally break it down to:

- perform any inversion of control necessary so that the controllers are given their model obejcts (tell, don't ask)
- define protocols describing the existing model API
- make the existing model classes conform to the protocols
- make the controller objects use these protocols instead of the model classes
- define `NSManagedObject` subclasses that conform to the protocols
- ensure the managed object subclasses are specified in the managed object model